# Is treated bamboo, kosher for schach please? (Treated to prevent ruin by water.)

Tags: halacha, sukkot

Can anyone please tell me if bamboo that has been treated to withstand water, is kosher to be used as schach? I've heard divergent opinions.
Many thanks and G-d bless.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53098/pressure-treated-lumber-for-schach

Comment: Why would you think that if it’s treated that makes it invalid? If you could cite your sources that would greatly improve this post.

Comment: Hi Jacqueline R and welcome to Mi Yodeya. You've asked an interesting question, here. I think Gerhson's link would provide an answer by deduction. It seems that one of the main requirements is that the schach be made from a naturally growing material, which is what bamboo is, of course. Treated lumber may be used, so I can't see why treated bamboo would be any different. I gather that painted wood may not be used, but, I'm uncertain about that, or why the painting would invalidate it.

Comment: @DanF The concern for painted wood [or other materials] is whether or not once painted it is considered a new object and no longer maintain its original, natural character. However, R. Ovadiah Yosef (Chazon Ovadia Sukkot, pg. 32) rules that such additions are permitted altogether and in no way presents a problem, nor a problem of chatzitzah (barrier).

Comment: Don't forget that, like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but [does not offer professional advice](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734), and does not take the place of [seeking such advice from your rabbi](/q/9146).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with materials that are "treated to withstand rain" would be if *gezeirat tikra* (no differentiation from a roof; see Sukkah 14a) applies to it. Some are of the opinion that only material that are structurally similar to a roof (e.g. wide planks of wood) are subsumed in this *gezeirah* (see responsa Shaarei Yosher 1:28 and works cited there). As indicated in the question, there are different opinions and so one should consult their LOR.